# Agenda view with 'logic'

Tags: org-agenda

I'd like to set up agenda views with some logic. So example Todo state is `NEXT` with no schedule date. Can someone point me to some resources to make sense of this ?

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I get you but here is a link about [Custom Agenda Commands](https://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-custom-agenda-commands.html).

Comment: Welcome to Emacs! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: thanks. I am familiar with the basic custom agenda commands and have several custom agenda views. What I am trying to do is to have an agenda view that will list tasks that meet multiple conditions such as STATE: NEXT and TAG: @calls and is not scheduled